# Access event object from Backbone Marionette ItemView trigger

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I have the code below. I want to on `<Enter>` of the `input#editTodo`, I want to save the model (Todo). I figured I need to listen to the `keypress` event then check that the `keycode` is 13, if so I save the model ...

```
TodoView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    triggers: {
        "keypress #editTodo": "detectEnterAndSave"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.on("detectEnterAndSave", function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

But I cant seem to get the event object? If so how do I know what key is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
events: {
    'keypress #editTodo' : 'detectEnterAndSave'
},

detectEnterAndSave : function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but what I get is an object `{ collection: ..., model: ..., view: ... }`. I think this is expected from what I see in [Marionette docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#trigger-handler-arguments).

Comment: OK I got it. For that I need to use events instead of triggers